# Only allow owner of data to access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm use devise, and *belongs_to* to quickly add relations. For example:

```
rails generate devise User
rails generate scaffold Campaign name:string user:belongs_to
```

Tell me please, how can I allow access to data only for the owner of this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can access their campaigns as this:

```
current_user.campaigns
```

**CampaignsController**

```
def show
  #this will search only within current user campaigns.
  @campaign = current_user.campaigns.find_by(id: params[:id]).
  if campaign 
    #this campaign exists and its from current_user
   ...
  end
end

def index
  #only this user campaigns
  @campaigns = current_user.campaigns
end 

def new
  @campaign = current_user.campaigns.build
end

def create
  #This campaign is created with user_id = current_user.id
  @campaign = current_user.campaigns.build(campaign_params)
  @campaign.save
end

private

  def campaign_params
    params.require(:campaign).permit(:name)
  end
```

Comment: Thank you, Pablo! It works. Advise me please. I think this is a bad way to get the user ID in the form, right? - `<%= form.hidden_field :user_id, id: :campaign_user_id, :value => current_user.id %>` -  Is there a better way?

Comment: I updated the answer. You don't need to pass the user_id. It is current_user.id and you have it in the controller.